How to dispatch a keyup event on a TJSElement in TMS WEB Core?
I'm busy converting some JavaScript code over to Delphi and I'm trying to dispatch a keyup event on a TJSElement class.
In JavaScript, this is how I have done it:
layTable.querySelector(".dataTable-input").dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup"));

In Delphi, I've been able to get as far as to write the following:
layTable.ElementHandle.querySelector('.datatable-input').dispatchEvent();

But I'm not sure how the dispatchEvent() function works. It is expecting a event: JSValue parameter.
How can dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup")) be translated to Delphi code?

Since TMS WEB Core is more or less a wrapper for FPC's pas2js transpiler I'd always look into their sources. And also always consult a JS documentation on what I want to touch.
As per your case I'd recursively search all .pas files for TJSEvent, since every type in that projects has the prefix TJS. This also prevents me to have way too many results for just searching for Event. If you cannot manage searching with Embarcadero's IDE there are numerous alternatives like

text editors (Notepad++ can do this) or
Windows' command line tool findstr (f.e. findstr /i /s /c:TJSEvent E:\pas2js\*.pas)

available to achieve that. Which then should bring you to \packages\rtl\weborworker.pas, line 89:

TJSEvent = class external name 'Event'  (TJSObject)
...
  constructor new (aType : String); overload;


Wow - even the constructor which mostly is named .Create() is adapted to the JS original to make it more obvious. And that brings me to write this code (untested):
uses
  weborworker;
var
  e: TJSEvent;
begin
  e:= TJSEvent.new( 'keyup' );
  layTable.ElementHandle.querySelector( '.datatable-input' ).dispatchEvent( e );

